# get insights metrics and post info

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am stuck in my code 
I need to get insights info and some other info like reactions , description ...
My problem is I can't get for example reactions or comment info If I am using this method

```
$response->getGraphEdge();
```

I can get all insights info but for my comments or reactions info my script return 0

But if I use this method

```
$response->getDecodedBody();
```

I have all info I want but I can't go on the next result page

Here is my request

```
$data = $pageFeed_demotivateur->demo_request('GET' , 'XXXXXX/posts?fields=insights.metric(post_impressions_unique,post_video_views,post_consumptions),id,type,link,name,message,created_time,reactions.limit(0).summary(true),comments.limit(0).summary(true),shares&limit=100&since='.intval($last_year_start).'&until='.intval($last_year_end));
```

And the method demo_request

```
public function demo_request($method = 'GET' , $params){

    $request = $this->facebook->request($method, $params);

    try {
      $response = $this->facebook->getClient()->sendRequest($request);
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
      // When Graph returns an error
      echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
      // When validation fails or other local issues
      echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    }

    $posts = $response->getGraphEdge();     
    //$posts = $response->getDecodedBody(); Can't use next() method
    $all_posts = array();
    $all_post_info = array();

    if($this->facebook->next($posts)){  

        $posts_array = $posts->asArray();
        $all_posts = array_merge($posts_array, $all_posts);
        while($posts = $this->facebook->next($posts)){
            $posts_array = $posts->asArray();
            echo '<pre>';
            var_dump($posts);
            echo '</pre>';
            $all_posts = array_merge($posts_array, $all_posts);
        }

    }else{
        $posts_array = $posts->asArray();
        $all_posts = array_merge($posts_array, $all_posts);
    }

    return $all_posts;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `getGraphNode` instead?

Comment: Uncaught Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException: Unable to convert response from Graph to a GraphNode because the response looks like a GraphEdge

Comment: So the problem with getGraphEdge is that you can get the insights, but not the other fields? I think that might be because you are actually requesting both edges (insights) and fields at the same time here. Can you try if you can call the `asArray` method, and see what that gets you?

Comment: I think I don"t have choice , I have to use graphedge or graphnode